# Does たり mean to try?

Tags: meaning, translation

ヒッチに止められたりしなかったんですか？

Does the tari make the sentence mean " hitch tried to repeatedly stop you?" ? Or is it "weren't you stopped by hitch?

I read somewhere that tari is to do something over and over or is it omission? How do you know

Comment: It doesn't mean over and over at all. It means that there are other things that you omitted. So your example sentence means just "Did Hitch try to stop you?" but the one who asked the question implies that there are other things Hitch might have tried besides just stopping the person.

Comment: So if tari is omission, where does it imply she tried?

Comment: It's not just omission, it also adds certain amount of vagueness as far as I know. So instead of "Did Hitch stop you?", I'd say "Did Hitch try to stop you?" Is more appropriate. It's not a literal translation though as you really can't translate it literally.